# Unity ads, Video always fails to show

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code and after I execute it with a button console every time that prints out that video, it fails. Maybe I just don't know how to enable ads in Unity. I have test mode enabled. This is my code. :

**FIXED** i just needed to replace this line

> public string placementId = "rewardedVideo";

with this:

> Advertisement.Show(placementId, options);

private string gameId = "1523603";

```
void Start(){ 
        Advertisement.Initialize (gameId);
}
public void ShowAd (){
    var options = new ShowOptions();
    options.resultCallback = HandleShowResult;
    Debug.Log (Advertisement.IsReady ("rewardedVideo"));
    Advertisement.Show(gameId, options);
}

void HandleShowResult (ShowResult result){
    if(result == ShowResult.Finished) {
        Debug.Log("Video completed - Offer a reward to the player");
        OnemoreTry ();

    }else if(result == ShowResult.Skipped) {
        Debug.LogWarning("Video was skipped - Do NOT reward the player");

    }else if(result == ShowResult.Failed) {
        Debug.LogError("Video failed to show");
    }
}
```

Comment: `it fails` What does 'it fails' means? **How** does it fail?

Comment: It writes in the console video failed to show  so it executes last line